# CORS error while connecting Angular with spring boot for JWT

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cors, jwt

This is the error in browser console I get whenever I log in (make a post-call to the server

[image]

I am trying to connect angular and spring boot using REST for implementing JWT Authentication and Authorization.

This is my Angular service that makes a login call to the spring boot (http://localhost:8080/login) which is a default /login page which spring boot gives with spring-starter-security (* I think *)

```
export class JwtService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  submitData(credential){
    credential = JSON.stringify(credential);
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    return this._http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",credential);
  }
}
```

below is my spring boot security configuring class

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
 implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    private CustomAdminUserDetailService adminUserService;
    private AdminDao adminDao;


    public SecurityConfiguration(CustomAdminUserDetailService adminUserService, AdminDao adminDao) {
        super();
        this.adminUserService = adminUserService;
        this.adminDao = adminDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), this.adminDao))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(adminUserService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200/");
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addCorsMappings(registry);
    }
```

I have tested it with the postman and it works fine, giving proper response and the Bearer token as expected but it is not working with Angular

This is the screenshot when I am testing it with Postman

[image]

I have also tried including Allow-cross-origin header in the request as

```
export class JwtService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  submitData(credential){
    credential = JSON.stringify(credential);
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    reqHeader.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    return this._http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",credential,{headers:reqHeader});
  }
}
```

This is my restcontroller for `/home` (I haven't included `/login` as spring boot gives it by default *'I might be wrong cz i am not sure'*)

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class AdminController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

I tried debugging using spring boot and this is what i got,

```
2020-03-21 21:41:14.087[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking status of clustertest-shard-00-01-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.087[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Sending command '{"ismaster": 1, "$db": "admin", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1584807064, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "Qwv788i1WPfmVGkKUUq6jwsgR2U=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 6803351677173760002}}}' with request id 284 to database admin on connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:139947}] to server clustertest-shard-00-01-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.350[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Execution of command with request id 284 completed successfully in 262.49 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:139947}] to server clustertest-shard-00-01-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.351[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=clustertest-shard-00-00-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=336.3 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=clustertest-shard-00-01-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=303.9 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=335.4 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.784[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking status of clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.784[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Sending command '{"ismaster": 1, "$db": "admin", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1584807064, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "Qwv788i1WPfmVGkKUUq6jwsgR2U=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 6803351677173760002}}}' with request id 285 to database admin on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:157822}] to server clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.786[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking status of clustertest-shard-00-00-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:14.786[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Sending command '{"ismaster": 1, "$db": "admin", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1584807064, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "Qwv788i1WPfmVGkKUUq6jwsgR2U=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 6803351677173760002}}}' with request id 286 to database admin on connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:145988}] to server clustertest-shard-00-00-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:15.135[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Execution of command with request id 285 completed successfully in 351.23 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:157822}] to server clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:15.136[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Execution of command with request id 286 completed successfully in 349.71 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:145988}] to server clustertest-shard-00-00-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:15.136[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=clustertest-shard-00-00-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=336.3 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=clustertest-shard-00-01-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=303.9 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=338.7 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:15.136[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ngodb.net:27017][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.cluster              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=clustertest-shard-00-00-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=339.1 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=clustertest-shard-00-01-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=303.9 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}]}, roundTripTime=338.7 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.794[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[o-8080-Acceptor][0;39m [36mo.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Counting up[http-nio-8080-Acceptor] latch=1
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.795[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4050f960:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22fe2d9:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56785]], Read from buffer: [0]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.795[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4050f960:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22fe2d9:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56785]], Read direct from socket: [544]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.795[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Received [POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

{"username":"nachu","password":"nachu"}]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.796[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Security checking request POST /login
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.797[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m   No applicable constraints defined
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.797[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Not subject to any constraint
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.797[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'GET /logout'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No matches found
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtAuthenticationFilter'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mc.n.p.util.JwtAuthenticationFilter      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request is to process authentication
in attempt authentication
spring boot generating token to authenticate authentication
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.802[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.802[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.d.m.r.query.StringBasedMongoQuery   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Created query Document{{username=nachu}} for Document{{}} fields.
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.803[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m find using query: { "username" : "nachu"} fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.nachu.project.repository.AdminUser in collection: admin_user
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:17.805[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Sending command '{"find": "admin_user", "filter": {"username": "nachu"}, "limit": 2, "$db": "school", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1584807074, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "Mb5v7hdn1UfUpwhsk+1/C1JJTi8=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 6803351677173760002}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "9QYFHA01TUyDwe0kXrY5DQ==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 287 to database school on connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:150674}] to server clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.079[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.protocol.command     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Execution of command with request id 287 completed successfully in 273.69 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:150674}] to server clustertest-shard-00-02-rmt6q.mongodb.net:27017
User role is : [ADMIN]
spring boot successfully authentication the user
generating jwt token
sending response to the user
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.441[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@22d45307
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.441[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.442[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4050f960:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22fe2d9:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56785]], Read from buffer: [0]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.442[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4050f960:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22fe2d9:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56785]], Read direct from socket: [0]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.443[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4050f960:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22fe2d9:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56785]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:18.444[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4050f960:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22fe2d9:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56785]]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.323[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(4)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1: accepted socket from [127.0.0.1:56788]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.323[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(4)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1: (port 56134) op = 80
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.334[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: accepted socket from [127.0.0.1:56790]
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.339[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: (port 56135) op = 80
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.339[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.loader                          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: name = "[Ljava.rmi.server.ObjID;", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@25a78f17
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.339[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.loader                          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.server.ObjID", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@25a78f17
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.339[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.loader                          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@25a78f17
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.340[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.loader                          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.dgc.Lease", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@25a78f17
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.340[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.loader                          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.dgc.VMID", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@25a78f17
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.340[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.loader                          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: name = "[B", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@25a78f17
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.341[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(4)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1: (port 56134) op = 82
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.341[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(4)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1: (port 56134) op = 84
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.342[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: (port 56135) op = 80
[2m2020-03-21 21:41:22.346[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m10132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(5)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36msun.rmi.transport.tcp                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1: (port 56135) op = 80
```

This is the AuthenticationFilter class i am using

```java
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
//      super();
        System.out.println("in constructor");
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("in attempt authentication");
        LoginViewModel credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginViewModel.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            System.out.println("in json parse");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            System.out.println("in json map");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("in io exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("spring boot generating token to authenticate authentication");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                credentials.getUsername(), 
                credentials.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>());

        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("spring boot successfully authentication the user");
        System.out.println("generating jwt token");

        User user =  (User) authResult.getPrincipal();

        String token = JWT.create()
                        .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                        .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1))
                        .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512("adhfjhewr******fk23"));

        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
        System.out.println("sending response to the user");
    }
```

[image: My Network tab]

Headers in the request are

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

***How*** is the first question but **Why** is more important

### **Some help would be appreciated. Thank you**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I've put your pictures in, but some of them contain code. It would be better if you could replace them with just code rather than pictures. This applies to log output too, pls. If I've made any mistakes let me know in the comments. Thx.

Comment: can you show message in network tab.? what is the origin which is getting passed in request header?

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram I have included the *Network Tab* and *Request Header* in the question.

Comment: Your frontend JavaScript code isn’t adding an Authorization request header to the request.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Authorization is the next step but here I am having a problem with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mistakenly written * instead of /** in addCorsMappings() method

Now the method looks like

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:8080");
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addCorsMappings(registry);
    }
```

Also, After that Angular client wasn't able to grab the response and was getting **null**
in the response so I modifed it as

```
submitData(credential){
    credential = JSON.stringify(credential);
    return this._http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",credential,{observe: 'response'});
  }
```

Now I am getting Http response.

### I hope this would help others.

## And Thank you all who tried to solve my problem and given their precious time.

Answer (score 3):

You should enable `CORS` on your backend. 
Angular app is served at `http://localhost:4200` and browser refuses to make request to another domain (in this case `http://localhost:8080`).
[More information on CORS.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

So, you should whitelist your **front-end** url on your **backend** app.

You can easily do that with Spring Boot by adding some lines in your `Application` class :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...

    /**
     * CORS configuration
     */
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200"
                )
                .allowedMethods(
                        "GET",
                        "PUT",
                        "POST",
                        "DELETE",
                        "PATCH",
                        "OPTIONS"
                );
    }

    ...
```

You should also check your Spring Security configuration. 
CORS should be enabled via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }
}
```

More details in [Spring official documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: Even though I had done that in the **SecurityConfiguration** class, I did try adding it in the **main application class** but it didn't work either giving the same error.

Comment: please share your Spring Boot Security config

Comment: I just added it, now you can check my SecurityConfiguration Class

Comment: I've just edited my answer with additional Spring security config, you have to enable `CORS`.

Comment: I added cors() as you explained but it didn't work either, giving the same error `@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.csrf().disable()
   .cors()
   .and()
   .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
   .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), this.adminDao))
   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
   .and()
   .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
   .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("ADMIN");
 }`

Comment: try setting allowed origins as .allowedOrigins(
                     "http://localhost:4200", 
                     "http://localhost:8080"
             )